# Abortar Hilo c#

Tags: c#, hilos

Necesito abortar un hilo. El hilo siempre se mantiene en estado "**RUNNING**", si hubiese la manera de hacer una comparación de esta manera:

```
if (hilo.threadstate == hilo.threadstate.running)
{
    hilo.abort();
}
```

Si ya hay un hilo corriendo que lo aborte.

Comment: Porque iniciar un hilo para abortarlo?¿, con el poco codigo que brindas no se te puede ayudar, que tipo de thread utilizas?, seria bueno que muestres mas codigo o mejores tu pregunta, además no creo que sea una buena idea hacer lo que quieres, detener un hilo puede ser muy perjudicial.

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar todo tu codigo y explicar que es lo que deseas hacer, para poder darte una salida alterna y no **abortes** el hilo.

Comment: seguramente tendrás un bucle infinito en el hilo, puedes mostrar el código que ejecuta el Thread?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es reiniciar el hilo te recomiendo cambiar el planteamiento de la pregunta.